# How to achieve same functionality as iOS Mail app with swipeable tableview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitableview

I am trying to replicate the same type of functionality as the stock iOS Mail app when a user swipes a tableview cell as currently seen here:

[image]

There are 3 options: More, Flag, and Archive. When the user taps on any one of the 3, the background color changes to indicate it's in a highlighted state. However, the icon and text do not change color.

I am trying to achieve the same effect.

I am following this tutorial guide to make a custom swipeable tableview cell using gestures:

[How To Make A Swipeable Table View Cell With Actions – Without Going Nuts With Scroll Views](https://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views)

Currently I have this set up:

[image]

In each cell contains 3 `UIViews`, where each `UIView` contains an `UIImageView` and `UILabel` representing Dirty, Edit, Delete.

I am adding tap gestures to the 3 `UIViews` like so:

```
let dirtyButtonView = cell.viewWithTag(7)
let editButtonView = cell.viewWithTag(8)
let deleteButtonView = cell.viewWithTag(9)

let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyVC.buttonPressed))
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
dirtyButtonView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
editButtonView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
deleteButtonView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

However, I cannot achieve the highlight state functionality that the Mail app has when a user selects one of the 3 options.

I'm not sure if this is the correct implementation, i.e. having a `UIView` and adding a gesture to it?

How can I achieve something similar to the iOS Mail app swipe functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found exactly what I was looking for, [SwipeCellKit](https://github.com/jerkoch/SwipeCellKit), by jerkoch. This library performs the same exact actions as the stock iOS Mail app does when swiping to the left. No need to deal with different `UIViews` and `UIButtons`.

To use, simply conform to the `SwipeTableViewCellDelegate`, and use it in `editActionsForRowAt` like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
    guard orientation == .right else { return nil }

    let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in
        // handle action by updating model with deletion
    }

    // customize the action appearance
    deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "delete")

    return [deleteAction]
}
```

Make sure to change the cell's class to `SwipeTableViewCell` and set its delegate like so: `cell.delegate = self`.

Comment: @ Pangu Can you please provide how to handle the delete part. Because I am getting a crash whenswipe it

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the [SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell) by CEWendel. It looks like it has exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

May be late to answer this, but in case anyone else is looking -  consider this read to answer the question: https://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views